# Send data from an iPhone to a Web service

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm developing an iPad application in which a user fills in their details and presses a submit button, which sends the information to a specific Web server (which will later be viewed by a person)

As far as protocols for Web services are concerned, I know JSON and XML. Are there any other protocols that I should be looking into? (or perhaps by a different method completely)

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to send text info to server you can try this code:

```
NSString *textdata = [YourTextField text];
NSString *anotherTextdata = [YourAnotherTextField text];

NSString *urlpath;
urlpath = [@"http://yoursiteapiurl.com/" stringByAppendingString:@"yourserverfile.php?textdata="];
urlpath = [urlpath stringByAppendingString:textdata];
urlpath = [urlpath stringByAppendingString:@"&anotherTextData="];
urlpath = [urlpath stringByAppendingString:anotherTextdata];

NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlpath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *a = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

The variable `a` will have the response of this URL. The server could send XML and then you can parse that XML using any XML parsing technique.

Comment: @saurab:thanks man...need a little help..my app has got text box ..where i m going to enter data..so which place exactly my text got to get appended in the above code u ve given me

Comment: Can someone please explain why the down votes!! I really hates downvotes without comments!

Comment: Poorly formatted code in conjunction with poorly formatted English is not welcome.

Comment: @bradley.ayers - then you should edit this answer... there is no need to downvote.

Comment: @Saurabh If you improve the answer, I will release the down vote.

Comment: You are allocating a lot of `NSString`s where it's not needed, I'd change it to:

`NSString *urlpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yoursiteapiurl.com/yourserverfile.php?textdata=%@&anotherTextData=%@", textData, anotherTextData];`

Comment: @Saurabh. I am developing shopping app. Using touchXML or NSXmlparser. How can I update or synchronize server data. I mean when I click on addtocart, it also update view cart on website. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use tbxml for it, its very easy to implement. Follow the link

http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html

Comment: i don want to parse an xml data ...wat i want is to send data to a server

Answer (score 1):

If sending the data over HTTP is an option, I would recommend you look into the excellent [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library. As for encoding, I've found the [json-framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) library to be good.

Answer (score 0):

Use AFNetworking for [this.](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git)

AFNetworking is smart enough to load and process structured data over the network, as well as plain old HTTP requests. In particular, it supports JSON, XML and Property Lists (plists).