# sending data to a server from ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad

i m developing an ipad app for hospital management were information is filled in the user interface and on the click of a button the data is to be transfered to an external database(which later be viewed)...what are the steps required

Comment: depends on the database you have to interact with, and also depends on the type of data being passed, and if you have access to the back end server.

Comment: mssql, or mysql? you will need to send the information to the backend server(in a secure fashion), then get the a service on the server to run over the items and import them from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a webservice (like Saurabh said), for instance a PHP file using an mySQL connection would do fine.

To post the data (unsecured) to the service you can dome something like this:

```
NSString *post = @"key1=val1&key2=val2";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-    Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

[Read the NSURLConnection documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create webservices on your server to add data in your database
see the answer of this question to know how to send data

[Send data from an iPhone to a Web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547644/send-data-from-an-iphone-to-a-web-service/5547740#5547740)