# send text to servlet via iphone

Tags: iphone, servlets, httpconnection

what i am trying to do is, i am creating a very simple iphone app, textfield and a button that when pressed it should send the text in the text field to a servlet hosted locally (glass fish 3.1.1) and just to make sure the request is done i type a simple 
`system.out.println("Request received");` 
and each time i hit the button and i go to check the server log, it empty !
i tried the same url in the browser then check the log,"Request received" is in the log.

the method connected to the button is:

`-(IBAction) connectToServer:(id)sender{
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/Test/Home"]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
}`

i really dont know if i am missing any thing here, any help ??

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580803/sending-data-to-a-server-from-ipad/5581119#5581119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't started the connection

So, your action's method should look like:

```
- (IBAction)connectToServer:(id)sender {
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/Test/Home"]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    [theConnection start];
}
```

Or, you may use a different initializer:

```
- (IBAction)connectToServer:(id)sender {
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/Test/Home"]];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
}
```

Or

```
- (IBAction)connectToServer:(id)sender {
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/Test/Home"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}
```

Comment: And don't forget about memory management if you don't use ARC :)

Comment: Have you implemented NSURLConnection delegate's methods?